# If Statement With Blank Variable

Tags: bash, if-statement

I can't get this to work correctly. If the wifissid is blank, it needs to display "Wireless: Not Connected". If the wifissid is not blank, it needs to display "Wireless: Connected To $wifissid"

```
wifissid=Test

if [ $wifissid = "*" ]; then
  WirelessOutput="       Wireless: Connected To $wifissid"
else
  WirelessOutput="       Wireless: Not Connected"
  exit
fi

echo "  $WirelessOutput"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The `! -z` checks to see if `$wifissid` is not (`!`) empty/null (`-z`). Or use `-n` which basically is the same as `! -z`. More details on these operators [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
wifissid=Test

# if [ -n "$wifissid" ]; then
if [ ! -z "$wifissid" ]; then
  WirelessOutput="       Wireless: Connected To $wifissid"
else
  WirelessOutput="       Wireless: Not Connected"
fi

echo "  $WirelessOutput"
exit
```

Also, I didn’t understand why you had an `exit` in the `else` statement since that would prevent the `echo` from ever happening. So I removed that and added it to the bottom of the script.

Additionally, I added `#!/bin/bash` to the top of the script because that is just something you should get in the habit of doing. It helps prevent issues such as if this script were running as a cron job, the default `sh` instead of `bash` would interpret the script & it would fail.

Might seem like small things, but it’s the little things that will drive you nuts if/when things don’t work out as expected.

Comment: Or just `-n` instead of `! -z`.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out a few seconds after posting the question.